# Формат HH:MM в RangeBar

Tags: java, android

Я использую [Ermodo Range Bar](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar), и дело в том что мне нужно отобразить минимальное значение и максимально значение в часах и минутах... То есть типа этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Сам код:

```
public class FilterActivity extends Activity {
private RangeBar rangebar;
final int SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filter_layout);

    final TextView mDepartMin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDepartMin);
    final TextView mDepartMax = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDepartMax);
    rangebar = (RangeBar) findViewById(R.id.rangebar1);
    rangebar.setTickCount(25 * SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
    rangebar.setTickHeight(0);
    rangebar.setThumbRadius(8);
    rangebar.setConnectingLineWeight(3);

    mDepartMin.setText("" + (rangebar.getLeftIndex() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION) + ":" + SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rangebar.getLeftIndex() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION));
    mDepartMax.setText("" + (rangebar.getRightIndex() / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION) + ":" + SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rangebar.getRightIndex() % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION));

    rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIndexChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftThumbIndex, int rightThumbIndex) {
            int minHour = leftThumbIndex / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
            int minMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (leftThumbIndex % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
            int maxHour = rightThumbIndex / SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION;
            int maxMinute = SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION * (rightThumbIndex % SMALLEST_HOUR_FRACTION);
            mDepartMin.setText(minHour + ":" + minMinute);
            mDepartMax.setText(maxHour + ":" + maxMinute);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Сейчас выглядет вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, Как формат H:M поменять на HH:MM?

Comment: Раз уж вы работаете со временем, то, видимо, вам нужно работать с типом `Date` (и перед выводом преобразовывать в строку нужного вида через `SimpleDateFormat`), а не с типом `int`.

Comment: то есть вы имеете ввиду преобразовать int to Date??

Comment: Вообще, раз это время, то оно изначально должно быть в `Date`, как вы дальше собираетесь работать со временем и датами, используя тип `int`

Comment: Не подумал, как теперь изменить подскажите пожалуйсста!

Comment: Ну тут в двух словах не подскажешь. Изучите, как работать с классом `Date`, либо даже удобнее, с классом `Calendar` - извлекать из него отдельно часы, минуты для указания значений в `RangeBar`, преобразовывать дату в строку нужного вида и тп. и вперед. Вот [посмотрите](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/date.php) для начала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mDepartMin.setText(getFormattedDate(minHour,minMinute));
mDepartMax.setText(getFormattedDate(maxHour,maxMinute));

public static String getFormattedDate(int hour, int minute) {
    Calendar cale = Calendar.getInstance();
    cale.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cale.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    return dateFormat.format(cale.getTime());
}
```